# "Subclass" http and httProvider in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to make a separate `$http` module that does exactly the same thing as the original `$http` module, but appends a `baseURL` to every request.

I know that this can be done with an `interceptor`, but I don't want this behavior for every instantiation of `$http`, only for my "subclass" (not really possible in JS) called something like `$httpAPI` or something.

I've seen similar solutions that do a lot of work by hand. Can I just clone `$http` and put an interceptor on the cloned version?

Answer (score 0):

Create a service that has `$http` and an injectable parameter. Implemented the common function you use (get, post, put,... etc). In this new service the baseUrl can be either injected or hard coded.

```
function myHttp($http, baseUrl){

    var internalBaseUrl = baseUrl || 'http://www.baseUrl.com/';

    return {
        get: function(url){     
            return $http.get(baseUrl + url);
        },

        post: function(url, data){
            return $http.get(baseUrl + url, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for more of a way to do this at the interceptor level, but with a subclassed service